# Python .get() in Java

Tags: java, python

So if we have a dictionary in python we have the amazing `Dictionary.get(x ,y)`
if x exists, return whatever x value is, else return y. Does java have this method? I've looked around and can't find anything

Answer (score 10):

In Java 8, `Map` provides a [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method.

In earlier versions, you are probably stuck with either getting the value for the key with [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29), and null-checking it; or using something like:

```
value = (map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key) : defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

```
public interface Map<K,V>
```

where `K` is the key type and `V` is the value type.

Use `get` to get values for a given key.

```
V get(Object key) //returns null if this key doesn't exist
```

For the "or else return this" part, use the `getOrDefault` method (same link) [Map § `getOrDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)

```
default V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)
```

> Returns:
>   the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `defaultValue` if this map contains no mapping for the key

Comment: I have not used a map before, I will definitely look into it more but so far I don't fully understand your explanation due to my understanding.

Comment: Both answers here include a link to the documentation for `Map`. Read those, as a complete explanation on how `Map` works would be too long for an answer here.

Comment: Im reading it and it says it is part of the dictionary class, mapping a key to a value, this seems so much easier than using the other style.                          HashMap<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<String, integer>();      Why are there so many styles of writing the same thing in java?

Comment: It's not part of `Dictionary`. It's an interface and it _replaces_ `Dictionary`, which is now obsolete.

Comment: @Hello, you still need the type arguments. You can write what you wrote, or you can write `Map<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<>();`. They are equivalent. As to why so many styles, part of it is type safety, and part of it is history. There are probably other partial explanations as well.

Comment: I do not understand what is happening at public interface Map<K,V>

Comment: The `Map` keys and values can have _any_ type. However, they must all be the _same_ type. If you put `Object`, then any type will be suitable (because everything extends `Object`), but `Map` doesn't work that way. They all have to be the same class. So instead, you represent the types of the keys and values with `K` and `V`.